# COMET javascript library

Tags: javascript, comet

I am looking for a simple and reliable Comet javascript library. I want to keep a persistent streaming of data from my server (via PHP script) to the client side. I tried building my own using the iframe technique, but there are lots of issues with safari which I experienced. I am just hoping someone else has created a simple library for it?

Answer (score 6):

There is a [jquery comet plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Comet)
Probably the best version though is the [Dojo library](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/about)

I have a quick list of commands I used to get a jetty server with comet up and running [here](http://www.hallofbrightcarvings.com/getting-started-with-comet/)

Answer (score 2):

It's not just the javascript library that you need, but a server-side implementation as well. Depending on your needs, you'll need to pick a proper implementation.

You mentioned PHP, which is typically difficult with long-held requests. Other options include having a separate server for your comet requests, or using a SaaS solution, such as [WebSync OnDemand](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync).

Depending on which option you pick for the server, you will have one or more javascript clients available. But you need to determine your server implementation first, then use the appropriate javascript implementation to match.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.ape-project.org/ Pretty quick setup process.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried JSON-RPC.  Apparently Dojo has good support for it, though I haven't tried it thoroughly

[JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)

[Dojo Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/ajax-transports/remote-procedure-call-rpc)